# Join SQL Tables with Unique Data (Not same number of columns!)

Tags: sql

How can I join three or four SQL tables that DO NOT have an equal amount of rows while ensuring that there are no duplicates of a primary/foreign key?

Structure:

Table1: id, first_name, last_name, email

Table2: id (independent of id in table 1), name, location, table1_id, table2_id

Table3: id, name, location

I want all of the data from table 1, then all of the data from table 2 corresponding with the table1_id without duplicates.

Kind of tricky for a new guy...

Comment: What does table3 have to do with the question?

Comment: What do you mean "all of the data from table 2 corresponding with the table1_id without duplicates"?  Can you provide sample data to illustrate what issue you are concerned about?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you want to do with Table3.

A **LEFT JOIN** returns all records from the **LEFT** table, and the matched records from the right table. If there is no match (from the right side), then the result is NULL.

So per example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 AS t
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS tt
ON t.id = tt.id
```

The **LEFT** table refers to the table statement before the LEFT JOIN, and the **RIGHT** table refers to the table statement after the LEFT JOIN. If you want to add in Table3 as well, use the same logic:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 AS t
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS tt
ON t.id = tt.id
LEFT JOIN Table3 AS ttt
ON t.id = ttt.id
```

Note, that I use alias names for the tables (by using AS), so that I can more easily refer to a specific table. For example, t refers to Table1, tt refers to Table2, and ttt refers to Table3.

Joins are often used in SQL, therefore it is useful to look into: INNER JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, FULL JOIN, and SELF JOIN, as well.

Hope this helps.

Good luck with learning!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use an `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.table1_id
```

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding your need.

Comment: I don't think so. Looks more like a LEFT JOIN, since he wants all the data from table1.

Comment: Doh, I thought that, then wrote INNER anyway. Thanks.